# How to Find 5 consecutive "0" in file?

Tags: text-processing

I have the following data in a text file:

```
Name,7/27,7/28,7/29,7/30,7/31,8/1,8/2,8/3,8/4
abc,5,3,8,8,0,0,2,0,11
def,6,7,0,0,0,0,0,2,5
ghi,1,3,5,2,0,0,5,3,6
```

I need to find out which file (the "Name" column the file name) is giving 5 consecutive `0` as output.
In this example, that would be `def`.

Comment: Should a line with _six_ (or more) consecutive zeros be reported?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'd probably do this in `awk`, using `,` as a delimiter:

```
$ awk -F, '/,0,0,0,0,0/{print $1}' file 
def
```

However, that will also catch a line like this:

```
mno,6,7,0,0,0,0,0.5
```

To avoid that, match only if the last `0` is followed by a `,` or the end of the line:

```
awk -F, '/,0,0,0,0,0(,|$)/{print $1}' file
```

Comment: This will fail if a line has more than 5 zeros (the question is not clear on what is needed - at least 5 or exactly 5):




  $ cat ttt  
  Name,7/27,7/28,7/29,7/30,7/31,8/1,8/2,8/3,8/4  
  abc,5,3,8,8,0,0,2,0,11  
  def,6,7,0,0,0,0,0,2,5  
  ghi,1,3,5,2,0,0,5,3,6  
  jkl,6,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,5  
  $ awk -F, '/,0,0,0,0,0(,|$)/{print $1}' ttt  
  def  
  jkl  
  $

Comment: @HoppingBunny the question asks for "5 consecutive `0`". If a line has 45 consecutive zeros, that means it also has five consecutive zeros by definition. Seems perfectly clear to me, I don't know why you would think it should exclude more than 5. Perhaps you meant to comment on the OP instead?

Answer (score 4):

```
grep '0,0,0,0,0' file.txt
```

prints the matching line: `def,6,7,0,0,0,0,0,2,5`

```
grep '0,0,0,0,0' file.txt | cut -d, -f1
```

prints the first field using `,` as delimiter: `def`

Comment: This will be fine if the file contains only single-digit numbers - you might want to enforce word boundaries to the pattern like `\b0,0,0,0,0\b` to prevent matches on sequences like `10,0,0,0,0`

Comment: @steeldriver, unfortunately `\b0,0,0,0,0\b` will also match on sequences like `12.0,0,0,0,0.5`.

Answer (score 1):

To get the desired output we may try the below commands.

Gnu sed

```
$ sed -nE 'G;y/,/\n/;/(\n0){5}\n/P' file

$ awk -F, '/(,0){5}(,|$)/ && $0 =$1""' file

$ grep -oP '^[^,]+(?=.*?(,0){5}(,|$))' file
```

Grep with PC Re mode turned on we look for the five consecutive   `,0` inside a lookahead so that it doesn't get included un the output bag of grep.

Answer (score 1):

**using Raku (née Perl6)**

Below is an answer that tries to incorporate (and overcome) the objections mentioned by @J-L and @terdon. Also, lines with 5-or-more consecutive zeros are returned. Start first by expanding the test file:

```
$ cat 5or6_consec_zeros.txt
Name,X,7/27,7/28,7/29,7/30,7/31,8/1,8/2,8/3,8/4
abc,N,5,3,8,8,0,0,0,0,11
def,Y,6,7,0,0,0,0,0,2,5
ghi,N,1,3,5,2,0,0,5,3,6
jkl,N,1,3,5,2,0,0,0,0,0.5
mno,N,7.0,0,0,0,0,2,3,4,5
pqr,Y,1,3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0
stu,Y,1,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,3
vwx,Y,1,3,8,7,0,0,0,0,0
```

The -ne command line flag tells Raku to run the code line-by-line. The regex tries to match two tokens. In the first token it tries to match exactly 5 repeats of a "`,0`" two-character sequence. In the second token the regex tries to match either a trailing comma or end-of-line `$$` token (after @terdon):

[Note in Raku the `|` alternation operator implements the longest-token-matching (LTM) strategy. If at some point you need to implement a Perl5-like "first-matching" strategy in Raku, you use Raku's `||` "first-matching" alternation operator].

```
$ raku -ne 'when / [\,0]**5 [\,|$$] /  -> { .put };' 5or6_consec_zeros.txt
def,Y,6,7,0,0,0,0,0,2,5
pqr,Y,1,3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0
stu,Y,1,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,3
vwx,Y,1,3,8,7,0,0,0,0,0
```

To only return the first "column" of (essentially) comma-separated-values, Raku provides an explicit `split()` method:

```
$ raku -ne 'when / [\,0]**5 [\,|$$] /  -> { put .split(",")[0] };' 5or6_consec_zeros.txt
def
pqr
stu
vwx
```

https://raku.org/

Comment: I was wondering why you're using '$$' in your regex, as I
understand it that would only be useful for multi-line text,
and here a '$' works just as well.

Comment: @JosephBrenner admittedly for the code above the end-of-line '$$' zero-width token is overkill. (The traditional end-of-string '$' zero-width token works just as well for the above code). But I prefer to use '$$' whenever I keep whole lines intact, just in case I eventually change the code to read-in multiple line input (or even whole files) all at once.

Answer (score 0):

Sed can do this:

```
sed -n '/,0,0,0,0,0[,$]/p' file.txt | sed 's/,.*//'
```

Comment: `[,$]` matches on either the `,` or `$` characters.

Comment: You can run more than one `sed` command in one invocation, no need to run two separate instances piped together. Here `sed '/\(,0\)\{5\}\(,.*)\{0,1\}$/!d;s/,.*//'`